# Computing periodic continued fractions.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions

Compute $[1,2,3,\overline{1,4}]$ where $\overline{1,4}$ is the periodic part. I looked into explanations about that, but haven't come by an actual algorithm of computing such a thing. I know it is somehow: $$1+{1\over {2+{1\over 3+{1\over 1+{1\over 4+{1\over 1+{1\over 4}..............}}}}}}$$ but I can't see how I turn it into a numbrt. I could really use your help on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the period can be written as:
$$
x = 1+\frac{1}{4+\frac{1}{x}}
$$
At this point solve the quadratic:
$$
4x^2-4x-1 = 0 \Rightarrow x = \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
$$
and plug the positive solution into:
$$
1 + \frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{x}}}
$$

Comment: I arrived at: $x=1+{1\over {4+{1\over x}}}=1+{x\over {4x+1}}$ $\Rightarrow$ $x(4x+1)=4x+1+x$ $\Rightarrow$ $4x^2-4x-1=0$. How did you get what you got?

Comment: you are right, i've messed with calculations.

Comment: Thank you for exposing me to this method.

Comment: you are welcome!